# R: How to get a stack trace from the snow package

Tags: r, stack-trace

How can I get a stack trace back from a snow node after an error occurs? I'm getting errors when I use parSapply that do not occur when I use sapply. Snow is nice enough to give me the error message but it would be much more useful for me to have the kind of stack trace you can get from traceback(). So far I have tried:

```
options(showWarnCalls = T, showErrorCalls = T)
setDefaultClusterOptions(outfile = "/dev/tty")
```

and

```
options(error=traceback)
setDefaultClusterOptions(outfile = "/dev/tty")
```

without luck. I'm currently just testing with a local cluster ie:

```
makeSOCKcluster(c("localhost","localhost"))
```

but I will eventually be using an MPI cluster. Thanks.

Relevant versions:

- [snow package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html) (version 0.3-3)
- R 2.10.1
- Mac OS X 10.5.8

**Edit:** moved version info to bottom of question and added OS X

Answer (score 2):

For me, simple 
`options(error=traceback)`
works, snow just captures the error message with traceback from slave and shows it on the master's output.

Comment: hmm... OK, I guess I have to go back and check through what I may be doing wrong. Could you tell me what OS you use and what kind of cluster you make with make*Cluster? Thanks

Comment: I've tested it using SOCK cluster on linux.